# Why does MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero and MidpointRounding.ToEven do the same thing?

Tags: c#, .net, math, rounding-error

I've encountered a rather annoying problem.

Lets say I have the decimal 2.5, and I would like it rounded up.
All my research has told me is that:

```
Math.Round(2.5, 0, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)
```

Will give me the desired result.

Yet, when trying exactly that piece of code, it returns 2, not 3 as it should.
It even does it in a blank console application, as I was unsure if something else might be interfering with it.

Am I misunderstanding something here? Basically I just want the number I give it rounded up at all times.

Comment: I just tried it and it gives me 3.

Comment: Please post a complete compilable example that produces the incorrect result.

Comment: For clarification, are you saying you want even 2.001 to "round up" to 3?  If so, you want `Math.Ceiling` (for non-negative numbers) rather than `Math.Round`.

Comment: `I have the decimal 2.5, and I would like it rounded up, even it was 2.001` How can it be 2.001 if it is 2.5? *confused*

Comment: I am trying to convert an int in unity, to half it's value, always rounded up. And after doing another test in a console application, it does return 3 there correctly, even when using the .NET 2.0 subset that unity uses.    this is the code I have in a monobehavior script on a button click, it takes the number (5 in this case) halves it and then tries to round it up. `decimal calc = strong / 2; targetInput.text = (Math.Round(calc, 0, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)).ToString();` strong is the value gotten from the inputfield and targetInput is the input the result is sent to.

Comment: If you're trying to convert an `int` to half its value, rounded up, and it is always positive, then it's better to just do `int result = (value+1)/2;` (where `value` is an `int`)- and definitely don't be using `decimal` instead of `double`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mention in a comment that you want to `convert an int to half it's value, always rounded up`.

The most efficient way to do that, assuming that the int is positive, is simply:

```
int result = (value+1)/2;
```

If you need to handle positive AND negative values,

```
int result = (value+Math.Sign(x))/2;
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to use AwayFromZero. If a number ends up between two integers, like 1.5, it will round to 2. Otherwise, the rounding will happen normally.

[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.midpointrounding%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is the doc.

If you would like to always round up, use `Math.Ceiling(my_double);`.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the solution:

Basically in my code I was retrieving the an int from an input field, it was default cast as an int, so when I halved it, it was automatically rounded down (so for example, 5 / 2 = 2, not 2.5 as I was expecting).

The solution was to cast the input number do a decimal.

Code snippet with correction:

```
// strong is the input value
decimal calc = (decimal)strong / 2;

// targetInput is the input field for the result
targetInput.text = (Math.Round(calc, 0, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)).ToString();
```

Sorry if I wasted anyones time.

Comment: I strongly recommend that you stay away from `decimal` if you are writing a game. And see my answer for a far more optimal solution...

Comment: This is for a basic pen-and-paper character creator tool, where attributes can only be between 0 and 20, and some of them are calculated based on other attributes, as half their value rounded up. So while it is technically for a game, it is simply for generating a PDF with all the numbers, instead of players doing it themselves on a blank character sheet.

Comment: I see. Even so, it's a bit overkill when you can just use `((value+1)/2).ToString();`